# How to set timeout at runtime in JUnit Test Case

Tags: java, junit

I am using JUnit v4 as a test framework. I wanted to know how to set timeout at runtime in a Test Case?

I am using a `Parameterized` test, in which I have a list of `Scenario`s, which contain timeout value and some other fields. Each of these `Scenario`s may have different timeouts.

The `timeout` parameter is not helping me to achieve this.

```
@Test(timeout = getTimeOut())
public void secureLoginWithLongUsername() {
    // Test case goes here

}

private final long getTimeOut() {
    // I am doing some processing here to calculate timeOut dynamically
    long timeOut = scenario.getTimeOut();
    return timeOut;
}

@Parameters
public static Collection<Scenario[]> getParameters() {

    List<Scenario[]> scenarioList = new ArrayList<Scenario[]>();
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    List<Scenario> scenarios = config.getScenarios();
    for (Scenario scenario : scenarios) {
        scenarioList.add(new Scenario[] { scenario });
    }

    return scenarioList;
}

public class Configuration {
    private List<Scenario>   scenarios;
    //Some processing here
    public List<Scenario> getScenarios() {
        return scenarios;
    }
}

public class Scenario {
    private long   timeOut;
    private String   name;
    //Some more fields here
}
```

Please help me to find an alternative to set the timeout dynamically.

Comment: Does the [Timeout Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Timeout-for-tests#timeout-rule-applies-to-entire-test-class) help?

Comment: Let me redefine my question please. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @MoritzPetersen: Please have a look on my updated question.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you need to build it yourself, like:

```java
private Timer timer;

@After
public void terminateTimeout() {
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
    }
}

@Test
public void testTimeout() throws Exception {
    setTimeout(1000);
    // run test...
}

private void setTimeout(int duration) {
    final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
    timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            currentThread.interrupt();
        }
    }, duration);
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to ask you few questions. (1) Is it harmless to play with current thread? I hope, thread management must be taken care by JUnit internally. Does it have any side effects? (2) After the specified timeout, how can I mark the test case as failed? Somehow I need to call `org.junit.Assert.fail()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Moritz Petersen's answer, with simplification for a single test, and creating a test failure instead of an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21333910/1587329)

```
@Test
public void secureLoginWithLongUsername() {
  final Thread currentThread = Thread.currentThread();
  ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
  Future<?> timeout = scheduler.schedule(() -> currentThread.interrupt(), getTimeOut(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  try
  {
    // Test case goes here
  }
  catch (InterruptedException exception)
  {
     fail("thread was interrupted", exception);
  }
  timeout.cancel(true);
}
```